# Querying pivot table to return a list of referred rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, correlated-subquery, lateral-join

I have these 6 tables and query which returns everything I want, but I want to add a new pivot table, so I can get a list of rows linked to it.

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pg.id, p.prod_id)
    pg.group_name, p.name AS prod_name, v.version,
COALESCE((select default_something from version_child where version_id = v.id),
(select default_something from product_child where prod_id = p.prod_id),
(select default_something from product_group_child where group_id = pg.id)
) as something
FROM product_group pg
LEFT JOIN product p ON pg.id = p.group_id
LEFT JOIN version v ON v.prod_id = p.prod_id
ORDER BY pg.id, p.prod_id, v.version DESC;
```

Product Group Table

```
id  group_name
---------------------------
1   Nice
2   Very Nice
```

Product table

```
prod_id  name      group_id
---------------------------
1       something     2
2       psp3          1
3       bundle1       2
4       bundle2       1
```

Version Table

```
version_id  prod_id    version
---------------------------
1           2           1.0
2           2           1.1
3           3           2.3
4           1           0.1
5           4           0.4
6           1           0.2
```

Product Group Child Table

```
pgt_child_id  group_id    default_something
---------------------------------
1             2            root2
2             1            root1
```

Product Child table

```
pt_child_id  prod_id      default_something
-------------------------------------------
1             2            override2
```

Version Child Table

```
v_child_id  version_id    default_something
-------------------------------------------
1             3           winner
```

New Pivot Table

```
p_id.    version_id        prod_id
----------------------------------
1          3              2 
2          3              1 
3          5              1
```

Running the query [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bb68ada63d981e9e630698dd4a0bad0c) I get this now:

```
Group_name  prod_name    version    default_something
-----------------------------------------------------
Nice        psp3          1.1       override2
Nice        bundle2       0.4       root1
Very Nice   something     0.2.      root2
Very Nice   bundle1       2.3.      winner
```

What I want is like this

```
Group_name  prod_name    version    default_something  ref
-----------------------------------------------------------
Nice        psp3          1.1       override2           []
Nice        bundle2       0.4       root1               ["something"]
Very Nice   something     0.2.      root2               []
Very Nice   bundle1       2.3.      winner              ["something", "psp3"]
```

the `ref` column can be an array or comma separated string. Basically I need to add new column `ref` which joins pivot table with product and version table and return an array/comma separated string. Would be really helpful to have a modified dbfiddle to do  what I want it to it.

Comment: `version.version_id` vs. `id` in your query and fiddle, adds to the riddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution to your *riddle*:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pg.id, p.prod_id)
       pg.group_name, p.name AS prod_name, v.version
     , COALESCE((SELECT default_something FROM version_child WHERE version_id = v.id)
              , (SELECT default_something FROM product_child WHERE prod_id = p.prod_id)
              , (SELECT default_something FROM product_group_child WHERE group_id = pg.id)
               ) AS something
     , ARRAY(SELECT p1.name
             FROM   pivot pv
             JOIN   product p1 USING (prod_id)
             WHERE  pv.version_id = v.id
            ) AS ref
FROM   product_group pg
LEFT   JOIN product  p ON pg.id = p.group_id
LEFT   JOIN version  v ON v.prod_id = p.prod_id
ORDER  BY pg.id, p.prod_id, v.version DESC;
```

(Rather than an answer to a *question*.)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=db93d561b95dc439019ffb1ac9c816d9)*

Related:

- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159717/3684)

Alternatively, you could use a `LATERAL` subquery:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Comment: This works ! What about if we want `ref_rev` , so there is also an arrays of bundles? Pointing to a row ?

Comment: @user2616355 Please ask your new question as new *question* with the necessary details to make it clear. You can always link to this one for context.